# cordova admobpro ads not showing on Android devices

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, admob

I'm trying to put AdMob ads into my ionic android apps and to test the functionality I made an ionic app called AdMobTest. The plugin I'm using is the [cordova-admob-pro](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro) plugin. Here is my AdMob code:

```
var admobid = {};
if (/(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) { //Android
  admobid = {
    banner : 'ca-app-pub-2586564966169402/9782816366',
    interstitial : 'ca-app-pub-2586564966169402/8345912938',
    gotHereMsg1 : 'banner and interstitial have the android IDs'
  };
} else if (/(ipod|iphone|ipad)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) { //iOS
  admobid = {
    banner : 'Stand in iOS banner ID',
    interstitial: 'stand in iOS interstitial ID',
    gotHereMsg1 : 'banner and interstitial have the iOS IDs'
  };
} else { //Neither
  admobid = {
    gotHereMsg1 : 'banner and interstitial have no IDs'
  }
}

if (window.AdMob) {
  var admob = window.AdMob;
  admob.createBanner ({
    adId : admobid.banner,
    position : admob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
    isTesting : false, //False for live ; True for production
    autoShow : true
  });
  admob.prepareInterstitial ({
    adId : admobid.interstitial,
    autoShow : false
  });
  gotHereMsg2 = "window.AdMob is true";
} else {
  gotHereMsg2 = "window.AdMob is not true";
}

//Got an ID and the actual ID's
document.getElementById("getIdCheck").innerHTML = admobid.gotHereMsg1;
document.getElementById("bannerId").innerHTML = admobid.banner;
document.getElementById("interstitialId").innerHTML = admobid.interstitial;
//window.AdMob is true and banner is created + interstitial is prepared
document.getElementById("isWindowAdmob").innerHTML = gotHereMsg2;
//Show interstitial function is executed or has not been executed
document.getElementById("startInterstitial").onclick = function () {
  if (window.AdMob) {
    var admob = window.AdMob;
    admob.showInterstitial();
    gotHereMsg3 = "Show Interstitial function has been executed";
  } else {
    gotHereMsg3 = "Show Interstitial function has not been executed";
  }
  document.getElementById("checkInterstitial").innerHTML = gotHereMsg3;
}
```

To show what works I kept in the tests I did using the "gotHereMsg" variables. All the variables get where I want them to go.

So gotHereMsg1 has the msg about android IDs and the IDs are also correct.

gotHereMsg2 returns "window.AdMob is true" which means the createBanner and prepareInterstitial function are being executed.

Lastly gotHereMsg3 returns "Show Interstitial function has been executed" when I click the button.

Even though all the functions are being executed and it obviously recognizes window.AdMob no banners are being shown. Hopefully this provides enough information to resolve this.

It might be worth noting that I am using ionicv1 and that the code is written in the ionic's app.js file under the $ionicPlatform.ready function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have plenty of experience with admob and ionic v1.

First, dont use cordova-admob-pro, they (he?) literally steals revenue from you! [tuns of proof here](https://github.com/ratson/cordova-plugin-admob-free/issues/354#issuecomment-482807224)

Use [cordova-plugin-admob-free](https://github.com/ratson/cordova-plugin-admob-free)

```
if (window.admob !== undefined) {
            admob.banner.config({
                id: 'ca-app-pub-...',
                autoShow: true
            });

            // Create banner
            admob.banner.prepare();

            // Show the banner
            admob.banner.show();

            admob.interstitial.config({
                id: 'ca-app-pub-....',
                autoShow: false
            });
            admob.interstitial.prepare();
        }
```

Second I don't really see anything wrong...
I'd advise you to run the admob commands in the browser console windows while using remote inspect.....
and at same time watch the `adb logcat` to see if you get "NO FILL" or any other admob error

Comment: It works and after working on it after a couple days I don't even care why it didn't work before, thanks dude you're a saint.

Comment: Good to know! But, did you at least change to `cordova-plugin-admob-free` ? The other one can steal 30% of your revenue (or more because he has remote control from his server!)

Comment: I did but as far as I know after your app makes some large amount (don't remember the specifics) he starts taking only 2% of your ad revenue.

Comment: he hid the issues where we proved he was stealing 30%, basically he takes 0 until he thinks you made more than $1000, then he takes 2% and later (arbitrarily?) he starts taking 30%. He has a line of code that takes the value from the server and multiplies it and the value coming from the server was at 0.3 (30%) for some people (me included!) (that's why he disabled github issues)

Comment: @kevinfromspace I just added this link with tuns of proof that he steals 30% (or more who knows) https://github.com/ratson/cordova-plugin-admob-free/issues/354#issuecomment-482807224

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you late but damn if that is true that is scummy as hell, changed to free either way, thanks for the warning!